# What is the relationship between the Kurds and the Balochi?

Tags: iran, migration

Does anyone know how did the Balochi people, who nowadays live in South-eastern Iran and Western Pakistan, but speak North-Western Iranian languages (i.e. related to Kurdish), arrive there and what is their relation with the Kurds, except that they speak a similar language?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you mentioned, their linguistic relation to Kurdish does imply a shared history at some time in the past. As near as I can piece together from various sources online, the split may have happened as early as 200AD though, which in terms of languages (and history) is quite a long time indeed.

They have an [oral tradition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Baloch_people#Origins) of descent from [Hamza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamza_ibn_Abdul-Muttalib), an uncle of Muhammad, and then of being chased out of Aleppo in 680 AD. However, it appears that modern linguists don't feel that jibes very well with the linguistic data, which places their origins as a culture closer to the Caspian area.

There is a historical record of them living in eastern Iran, and being driven further east to modern-day [Balochistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balochistan,_Pakistan) in 972 by then Buyid Emir ['Adud Al-Dawla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'Adud_al-Dawla#Campaigns_in_eastern_Iran). Given that they have tended to be pastoralists (and occasional raiders) specializing in marginal territory, it makes sense to postulate that they slowly got pushed south-eastward from wherever they started out via similar mechanisms. But nobody really knows for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The Balochis lived in Aleppo at one point, and Aleppo was ruled by the Ayyubids who were Kurds. The Ayyubids are related to the Prophet Muhammad SAW and so are the Balochis (Via Ameer Hamza). So in my opinion it's safe to say that they may have a strong bond at some point in history. The connection of the Prophet Muhammad SAW and the Ayyubids is shown in the image I added to my answer. I hope you find it useful.

[image]

Comment: Please cite sources, especially for the image you have used. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well some Kurd and other historians claim that [Baluch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balak_(tribe)) today were known as 'Balaki' or Balaci one of ancient Kurdish tribes, because Balaki people speak mix dialects of Sorani and Kurmanji. If you look at the Baluchi language (not people) you will find exactly same pattern. The Baluchi language has more vocabulary in common with Kurmanji and Sorani is a mixture of both dialects. Iranian Kurds have no problem understanding Baluchi.

The sources are available online.The information about Balaki people and tribes also available online.Many Balaki tribes are still with exactly same names are still exist in Baluchistan.If you go through the list of Balaki tribes then match the same tribe names with Baluchi or current Baluchi tribes u will find the names are same there are more 10+ Balaki tribes are in Both Irani and Pakistani occupied Baluchistan.

Baluchi language itself is a vital proof.If you compare Baluchi language to Kurmanji and Sorani you will find almost 60% similarities way close to Kurmanji.Baluchi langauge has Sorani way of expressions and words are Kurmanji ..For example Tu buku rahi where are you going  is exactly with Sorani and Baluchi...Tu hatin (u arrived) in Kurmanji in baluchi it would be Tu Hate u arrived..Min turke niyan (I am not a Turk) is Kurmanji and same in Baluchi..They Kurd and Baluch live 10,000 miles away from each other but still the language is same it cant be a coincidence.

[Anthrogenica](https://anthrogenica.com/showthread.php?6758-Kurd-Baloch-Genetic-Similarity-via-Formal-Analysis)

Comment: Can you please add some source to your claims?

Comment: The sources are available online.The information about Balaki people and tribes also available online.Many Balaki tribes are still with exactly same names are still exist in Baluchistan.If you go through the list of Balaki tribes then match the same tribe names with Baluchi or current Baluchi tribes u will find the names are same there are more 10+ Balaki tribes are in Both Irani and Pakistani occupied Baluchistan.

Comment: Baluchi language itself is a vital proof.If you compare Baluchi language to Kurmanji and Sorani you will find almost 60% similarities way close to Kurmanji.Baluchi langauge has Sorani way of expressions and words are Kurmanji ..For example Tu buku rahi where are you going  is exactly with Sorani and Baluchi...Tu hatin (u arrived) in Kurmanji in baluchi it would be Tu Hate u arrived..Min turke niyan (I am not a Turk) is Kurmanji and same in Baluchi..They Kurd and Baluch live 10,000 miles away from each other but still the language is same it cant be a coincidence.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balak_(tribe)

Comment: https://anthrogenica.com/showthread.php?6758-Kurd-Baloch-Genetic-Similarity-via-Formal-Analysis

Comment: You should edit your question to include references: Comments in stack exchange are suppose to be ephemeral.

Answer (score -1):

Baloch and kurds are likely to be same they have many things in common and also they are genetically similar both of them lost their history and the strongest theory is that they are medes

Comment: This would be improved with some expansion and source references especially for the final clause.